# Java socket Client/Server connection refused issue

Tags: java, sockets, server, client

I have tried everything but nothing seems to work. I am loosing my mind and if anyone can help that would be great. I am writing a simple client/server code where i have echoclient.class which was given and i am suppose to run that against the server i write all on localhost. echoClient class sends a message and i am suppose to reverse the string and send it back.  i keep getting connection refused with echo client class but when i run echo server it works fine. any help???

this is my code:

```
   import java.io.BufferedReader;
   import java.io.IOException;
   import java.io.InputStreamReader;
   import java.io.PrintWriter;
   import java.net.Socket;
   import java.net.ServerSocket;

   public class EchoServer {

      public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        int port = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        String hostid = args[0];

           ServerSocket echoServer = new ServerSocket(port);
           System.out.println("Success");

        try{
           Socket echoClient = new Socket(hostid, port);
          echoClient = echoServer.accept();
           System.out.println("Connection made");

        // while(true){
          while ((echoServer.isClosed() != true) ||       
                   (echoClient.isClosed() != true)) {

           BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new   
                          InputStreamReader(echoClient.getInputStream()));

           String message = reader.readLine();
           PrintWriter writer = new  
                           PrintWriter(echoClient.getOutputStream(), true);

           while(message.contains("#") != true || message.contains("$") 
                                                                 != true){
           String builder = new 
                              StringBuilder(message).reverse().toString();

         writer.println(builder + "\n");
           }//writer.close();

          System.out.println(message + "\n");

             writer.close();
              echoServer.close();
             echoClient.close();
           }

        }catch(IOException ex){
           ex.printStackTrace();
        }
     }
 }
```

and this is the results:

```
 java -cp . EchoClient 127.0.0.1 1234
Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:345)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:211)
    at EchoClient.main(EchoClient.java:22)

and when i run this: 
java -cp . EchoServer 127.0.0.1 1234
Success
Connection made
```

Comment: thank you guys for promt responses you guys are awesome, i am just going crazy here

Answer (score 2):

- 'Connection refused' simply means that nothing was listening at the IP:port you tried to connect to. Probably you started the client before the server.
- The `isClosed()` tests are pointless. They only return true when *you* have closed the associated socket. They don't tell you anything about the state of the connection.
- ```
  Socket echoClient = new Socket(hostid, port);
  echoClient = echoServer.accept();
  ```

  is nonsense. Initializing a variable you're about to assign to in the very next line is at best a complete waste of time, and possibly a source of meaningless bugs. In this case you have both a socket leak and a self-connection. These don't explain the 'connection refused', but the self-connection would prevent your client from working once it had succeeded in connecting, as you aren't starting a new thread per connection.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are several problems with your code. First, it looks like your server and client are in the same class. I think they should be separate; you should have an echoServer.java and an echoClient.java. Next, assuming you have done this and are only showing the echoServer, in the line after 'try' you create a new echoClient with hostid and port. You don't need to do this, the
next line takes care of that, it should read Socket echoClient = echoServer.accept(); Further on, I think your while statement is wrong.

You should take a look at http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/84network/EchoServer.java.html and http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/84network/EchoClient.java.html

ron shenk